# Using Different Accounts with OpsHub to migrate TFS from on-premise to VSO

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, opshub

We currently do NOT have Azure AD setup (and don't need it).  I'm trying to use the OpsHub Migration Utility to move a TFS collection to the cloud.

However, the onPremise TFS is setup on a Domain.  While the accounts for the VSO project use the Microsoft accounts (which use only email address).

I know of how way to set pase the first set of the utility, (Provide EndPoint Details).

While I can use my Domain account and connect to the local TFS I'm unable to use that account to connect to the VSO project, nor can I find any way (Without using Azure AD) to setup my VSO project to allow my domain user account.  I searched the onpremise TFS security options and can't find a way to give access to the VSO email account either.

Is this not possible without Azure AD?

Answer (score 1):

Given the instructions on http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/migrate-team-projects-vs.aspx#what_data, I installed the utility on the actual TFS Server.

However, the server (being a server) had Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Enabled.

By disabling the feature, I was able to get the prompts to login the VSO using my email.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/chenley/archive/2011/03/10/how-to-turn-off-ie-esc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If we understand correctly, you want to connect to the VSO account for migration.
For this you don't have to add the user to your Local TFS User List. The user should only be used to create an End Point in the utility.

Let us elaborate it a little.
The migration utility expects you to have to end points 1. Your Source On-prem TFS Server and 2. Your VSO Cloud Account.

OpsHub Migration Utility now needs access to your On-Prem TFS and VSO by End Points created through these end points.

Quote:
"While I can use my Domain account and connect to the local TFS I'm unable to use that account to connect to the VSO project, nor can I find any way (Without using Azure AD) to setup my VSO project to allow my domain user account. I searched the onpremise TFS security options and can't find a way to give access to the VSO email account either. "

You don't have to add your VSO User to the On-Prem TFS. Instead, you have to create a End Point on that machine using that user. You can do so, either through OpsHub Utility > New Migration > Visual Studio Online Endpoint > Manage New Endpoints > Servers > Add or through Visual Studio > Server Explorer.

So, technically, you will have to use two separate users which exist in two different systems (On-prem TFS and VSO) to connect to End Points for the Utility.

Comment: Thanks Ops.  I only assumed the AD accounts because I initially didn't get the proper prompts to enter my VSO login information. Once I fixed the security issue, I got the proper prompts. Thanks.