# TFS 2010 migration to TFSOnline - OpsHub - Project template error

Tags: tfs, migration, opshub, azure-devops

I'm trying to migrate on-premises TFS 2010 projects to TFSOnline.

I'm getting "'<*project name*>' is missing in **********\DefaultCollection. Create a new project by the same name and with the 'Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum' template in your ********\DefaultCollection to continue."

Appreciate any help on this issue.

[Here is a screenshot of the project in TFSOnline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45Hm9.png)

[Here is a screenshot of the OpsHub error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnc4q.png)

Comment: Did you try clicking "Refresh" button to refresh the projects?

Comment: Access rights can be the issue.  Through which user have you created the end point on OVSMU tool? Does he have rights to access that particular project in VSTS?

Comment: Thanks Eddie but refresh didn't work. Looks like an issue with user accounts. We had one account for admin tasks and one with the regular access. Once I logged out of the regular account and logged in with the admin account I'm not getting that error anymore. But after user mapping I'm running into "Permission needed for logged in user in destination" and "Template customization or Template mismatch error". When I expand on the Permission error it shows that I'm logged in as the regular account and not the admin account. In my VS2015 and also in the browser I'm logged in as the admin.

Comment: I don't see any user login option in OpsHub, how do I make OpsHub use the admin account?

Comment: Update at 02/01/16 1812: I was able to solve the "Permission needed..." error by following this article (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26109932/using-different-accounts-with-opshub-to-migrate-tfs-from-on-premise-to-vso). However I'm still getting "Template customization or Template mismatch error". Source project is in TFS2010 and uses the Scrum template (I verified this by trying to create a new workitem and I got Bug, Product Backlog, Sprint etc.) and the new team project in TFSOnline also uses the Scrum template.

Comment: @NandhaMurugesan, This can come in couple of situations. 1) Template mismatch [As you told this is not the case] 2) Template customization one either of both sides. Please verify that you have not customized the template in source TFS or in the VSTS. If this is not the case, can you please send the expanded screen shot of the page on which you are getting this error on ovsmu@opshub.com.

Comment: I've fixed the template mismatch error by modifying the bug template and removing the "In Progress" field that was causing this issue. Now it fails on work item migration. Out of 3480 1913 failed and the error I see is "OpsHub-012010: Processing blocked - earlier event(s) for entity 27 have to be processed first.". Strange thing is that it looks like it fails for the same entity it is processing. WorkItem Id: 27, WorkItemType: Bug, Failure Description: OpsHub-012010: Processing blocked - earlier event(s) for entity 27 have to be processed first. Thoughts?

Comment: @NandhaMurugesan, This errors comes when there is any previous event (revision) failed to be processed. For example a workitem is having 5 revisions and 3rd is failed because of some reason, 4th and 5th will be failed with the error you have specified. You can hide those dependent failures by deselecting the "Show Dependent Failures" check-box on the failure screen. This will should only one failure for a workitem and that will have original error for which it is failed.

Comment: After I unchecked Show Dependent Failures, I'm seeing the error "OH-Connector-0143: Target system does not contain value : In Progress for field: State for entityType: Bug". I had to remove the "In Progress" field to overcome the "Template customization or Template mismatch error". I also checked the item 27 and its not in "In Progress" state and it doesn't have any sub tasks that are in the "In Progress" state as well. Is there anyway to just move the work items that are valid and don't move the items that error out?

Comment: @NandhaMurugesan, You have removed the the "In Progress" status value, but it must be there in the history of some workitems in your TFS. Utility is processing each of the revisions of the workitem and it is finding "In Progress" status in some revision. So, this customized data will not get migrated through the Utility.

Comment: I get the same error even after marking all the items in "In Progress" state as "Done". Error is "OH-Connector-0143: Target system does not contain value : In Progress for field: State for entityType: Bug"

Comment: @NandhaMurugesan, You have changed the current value of the work item status to Done, But Utility is migrating all revisions of the work item. In past your work items were having "In Progress" status which is still there in the revisions details. You can not remove that status value form revisions of the work items.

Comment: Is it even possible to to move work item data if the template needs to be changed?

Comment: @NandhaMurugesan, Assuming here you mean by "template needs to be changed" mean restoring to the default. In case of something was customized in any of the system field, restoring the template to default will also not work with this Utility.

Comment: I tried migrating just the work items and I'm running into one more error "OIMTFSApiExcpetion: OH-TFS-Connector-0030: Error occurred in executing operation getFileInformation. Server Error : TF30042: The database is full. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator.". I have a total of 5941 items and it fails on 4777 and migration is halted now. Can you please let me know how to fix this error?

Comment: I meant to say that I tried migrating just the version history and not the work items.

Comment: @NandhaMurugesan, Can you please share logs to ovsmu@opshub.com [Zip the "C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility\logs" directory and send it].

Comment: Sent it from my work account (nandha.murugesan@egate-solutions.com). Size is around 7MB.

Comment: I cleared space on the TFS Server, now I'm getting this error OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. TF10141: No files checked in: resolve the conflicts and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Issue here mentioned in the description was because of the user is not having enough permission on that project. Changing to the administrator account or user having permissions on that project resolved the issue.

> TF30042: The database is full. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator.

The above is because of your source TFS instance database is full.

Comment: This issue isn't solved yet. After clearing the space on the server, I'm getting the error OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. TF10141: No files checked in: resolve the conflicts and try again.

Comment: Hi, can you try clearing your workspace? 1. Close the utility, 2. Open Visual Studio and connect to the VSTS using the Team Explorer 3. In the Source Control tab, under 'Workspace' dropdown, select All Workspaces. Here, delete all the workspaces with name starting with OH-XXXXXX (Where X is any number). And then restart the OVSMU tool and retry the failure.

Comment: I dont see any workspaces with name starting with OH-* at all.

Comment: There should be. Are you performing the steps on the machine where OVSMU is? Have you connected to the target end point through Team Explorer?

Comment: I ran the 'OVSMU' tool directly on the TFS server itself and on the server I installed Team Explorer 2010 and on the workspaces dialog box I didnt see any starting with OH-.

Comment: That's highly unlikely. Send us the logs again, the error indicates issue with SCM checkin. There has to be a workspace created under which this action is being performed.

Comment: Try one thing, on the same machine, there would be an O:\ drive newly created by the tool. Clear out all the content of this drive and then start the utility and it's migration. (After this, the first time the tool runs, it should take some time to re-download data. So, ensure the tool gets enough time to run it's course)

Comment: Deleted all the files on the O drive and trying a new migration now.

Comment: Same error again, OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. TF10141: No files checked in: resolve the conflicts and try again. And this time also, I dont see any workspaces with name starting with OH-* at all

Comment: Can you please share logs to ovsmu@opshub.com [Zip the "C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility\logs" directory and send it].

Comment: Logs have been sent. I had to change the name of the following files in the folder “C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility\logs\Integrations\1_ts4devtfs\eGateProjects to egatesoln.visualstudio.com_ ts4devtfs”
1. eGateProjects to egatesoln.visualstudio.com_ TFS Source 1456536935240 Source TFS 1456536935247 _BlueSky_ Commit Information.txt to 1.txt
2. eGateProjects to egatesoln.visualstudio.com_ TFS Source 1456586327330 Source TFS 1456586327333 _BlueSky_ Commit Information.txt to 2.txt

Really appreciate your help.